# making simple_form text-fields transparent

Tags: html, css, simple-form

Hey I'd like my input text-fields for simple_form to be transparent.. meaning I would like it blend into the background of the page. Is there any way to do this? What's a good resource for styling simple_form?

here's the html with no css right now

```
<%= simple_form_for @reason do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :why, label: 'Tell us about it' %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Name (doesn\'t have to be your real name)' %>
    <%= f.input :location %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Put it out there", class: 'col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 btn btn-lg submit' %>
<% end %>
```

What I'm trying to do is make it look as if the user is writing text straight onto the background of the page when answering form questions

Comment: We are not going to just do your work for you... http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Show what you have so far or at least what you have tried that didn't work

Comment: how's that? I apologize I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class or id to your input field.

Example:

HTML -> `<input class="transparent_background" type="text" name="" value="">`

CSS -> `.transparent_background { background: transparent; }`

Hopefully this helps to get you started....Other than that though, it's hard to provide any help if your not more specific and/or provide us with what you currently have code wise...

Comment: <%= simple_form_for @reason do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :why, label: 'Tell us about it' %>
 <%= f.input :name, label: 'Name (doesn\'t have to be your real name)' %>
 <%= f.input :location %>
 <%= f.button :submit, "Put it out there", class: 'col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 btn btn-lg submit' %>
<% end %>

Comment: `<%= simple_form_for @reason do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :why, label: 'Tell us about it' %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Name (doesn\'t have to be your real name)' %>          <%= f.input :location %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Put it out there", class: 'col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 btn btn-lg submit' %>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example about a blend input text field in CSS, without classes or ids. Of course, since I'm not sure about how you have your code, this might not work for you:

**HTML example:**

```
<body>
    <span>Input field: </span>
    <input type="text" name="example" value=""/>
</body>
```

**CSS example:**

```
body {
color: white;
background-color: black;
}

input:nth-child(2) {
padding: 5px;
color: white;
background: transparent;
border: 2px solid yellow;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: sans-serif; 
}
```

And be aware that there is not a "good resource" for styling a form. The CSS is always different, and can change from one person to another. I hope this helps you.